# Swing objects declared as variable references or returned from methods?

Tags: java, swing

What are the differences between creating a Swing object as a variable reference or from being returned from a method? Which way is preferred?

For example:

```
JButton button = new JButton(){}
button.setText("Click Here");
```

Compared to:

```
public JButton Button(){
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setText("Select Folder");
    return button;
}
```

Comment: The question comes down to needs. Your second example is basically a factory method, which can generate a new instance of the button, preconfigured each time it's called. Ts might be useful if you're need to create a bunch of common buttons or wanted to provide a level of customisation to you component. In both case, you're going to have issues if you ever want to reference the buttons in some meaningful way

Comment: Without further context, neither is right or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, I don't see the need for the separate function.  A separate function would be useful if you wanted to create many buttons and change the defaults for the button, with all buttons having the same properties.